# Evaluate $\int\frac{x}{(x-a)(x-b)}$ where $a\neq b$

Tags: calculus, integration

I got  $\int\frac{x}{(x-a)(x-b)} $

$= x = A(x-b) + B(x-a)$

$x = b$

$b = A(b-b) + B(b-a)$

$b = Bb - Ba$

$\frac{-(Bb +b)}{b} = \frac{Ba}{b}$

$-B = \frac{Ba}{b}$

$-1 = \frac{a}{b}$

$a = -b$

$x = A(x + a) + B(x-a)$

Thats as far as I got..

Comment: Why did you add $a!=b$ in the title ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici He means $a \neq b$.

Comment: @Mike. Is this a notation I ignore ? My question is serious. Thanks for answering. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes, that is what I ment, sorry Im still getting use to stack exchange math notation. Just thought I would go with computer programing notation.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici As Benjiii says, a != b is how one would write $a \neq b$ when programming. It's also used fairly regularly in places where LaTeX/MathJax isn't enabled.

Comment: For more explanation look at [Partial fraction decompistion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)

Comment: @Mike. May I confess that the only programming languages I know and use are (listed by preference) : Fortran,  Fortran, Fortran, Fortran, Fortran and Fortran. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will assume that $a\ne b$. As you wrote, we want to find $A$ and $B$ such that $\frac{x}{(x-a)(x-b)}$ is identically equal to $\frac{A}{x-a}+\frac{B}{x-b}$.

Bring $\frac{A}{x-a}+\frac{B}{x-b}$ to the common denominator $(x-a)(x-b)$. We then need $x$ to be identically equal to the numerator $A(x-b)+B(x-a)$.

Putting $x=a$ we get $a=A(a-b)$ and therefore $A=\frac{a}{a-b}$. Similarly, we get $B=-\frac{b}{a-b}$.

Thus we want to find
$$\int\frac{1}{a-b}\left(\frac{a}{x-a}-\frac{b}{x-b}\right)\,dx.$$

Integrate. We get $\frac{1}{a-b}\left(a\ln(|x-a|)-b\ln(|x-b|)\right)+C$.  This can be put in various alternate forms.

Comment: What happens to the x in the numerator?

Comment: The numbers $A$ and $B$ were chosen so that $x$ is identically equal to $A(x-b)+B(x-a)$. That ensures that $\frac{x}{(x-a)(x-b)}$ is identically equal to $\frac{A}{x-a}+\frac{B}{x-b}$. You can check it out yourself. Take the $\frac{a}{a-b}\frac{1}{x-a}-\frac{b}{a-b}\frac{1}{x-b}$ that we obtained. Simplify this. After a while you will get $\frac{x}{(x-a)(x-b)}$. If it is too messy, use particular numbers like $a=5$, $b=2$.

Comment: It disappeared when creating the partial fraction since $A$ and $B$ where obtained by identification of lhs and rhs after having removed the denominator.